# C# Newtonsoft cant modify array in JSON file

Tags: c#, .net, json.net

I have a JSON file from this schema.
This has an **array** called accounts.

```
{
  "UplayExecutable": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Ubisoft\\Ubisoft Game Launcher\\UbisoftConnect.exe",
  "foo": "barr",
  "OpeningTime": 8,
  "accounts": [
    "abc@a.com , testpass",
    "rumirad@gmail.com , password2",
    "rumirad@outlook.com , password3",
    "rumirad@test.com , password3"
  ]
}
```

I am using .NET framework.I also use the newtonsoft library. I want to replace that array with a C # String array.
The string array is hard-coded because I want to test it here.
This has no compile errors. There is  a runtime error.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string json = File.ReadAllText("data.json");
            dynamic jsonObj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

            string[] accs = { "hi@hi.com , testpass", "hey@hey.com , abcd123", "hello@hello.com , hi123" };

            jsonObj["accounts"] = accs;
            string output = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonObj, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);

            File.WriteAllText("data.json", output);
        }
```

I want to know how to write a string array to a file as a json array

This is the error .I read the newtonsoft documentation but i could not find any solution

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your type casting is wrong. Beast way is to use c# object like below.
Create one class for json data

```
public class jsonData
    {
        public string UplayExecutable { get; set; }

        public string foo { get; set; }
        public int OpeningTime { get; set; }

        public string[] accounts { get; set; }
    }
```

Now, write code for reading json file, update accounts value and write back to file.

```
            string json = File.ReadAllText("data.json");
            var jsonObj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<jsonData>(json);

            string[] accs = { "hi@hi.com , testpass", "hey@hey.com , abcd123", "hello@hello.com , hi123" };

            jsonObj.accounts = accs;

            var jsonString = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonObj, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
            File.WriteAllText("data.json", jsonString);
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you cannot implicitly cast string[] to a JContainer the way you fix it is by assigning a JArray with string[] values inside., here is a fix to your code

```
string json = File.ReadAllText("data.json");
dynamic jsonObj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

string[] accs = { "hi@hi.com , testpass", "hey@hey.com , abcd123", "hello@hello.com , hi123" };

jsonObj["accounts"] = new JArray(accs);
string output = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonObj, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);

File.WriteAllText("data.json", output);
```

---

However we dont need to use dynamic typing here, we can just parse the JSON, replace the array then get the json back. like so

```
string json = File.ReadAllText("data.json");
var jObject = JObject.Parse(json);
string[] accs = { "hi@hi.com , testpass", "hey@hey.com , abcd123", "hello@hello.com , hi123" };
jObject["accounts"] = new JArray(accs);

File.WriteAllText("data.json", jObject.ToString(Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented) );
```